# How to prove that $\operatorname{div} (f\pmb v) = \operatorname{grad} f \cdot\pmb v + f \operatorname{div} \pmb v $ without coordinates?

Tags: vector-spaces

Here $f$ is a scalar and $\pmb v$ a vector field.

If there is no standard proof can this be proved in geometric algebra without a basis?

Comment: Yes, you can probably proof this using the Hodge star operator. If you are familiar with that, you should give it a try.

Comment: See also [Geometric calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus).

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548202/how-to-prove-that-div-fv-grad-f-v-div-v-f-without-coordinates).